# Difference between Present P. and Past P. for completed actions

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-aspect

I am always get into dilemma situation whether to use "I have" or "I had" for immediate past event.

For example:

> I have discussed with you
>   or
>   I had discussed with you

The discussion happened yesterday night and I am referring about same discussion while writing an email.

Comment: have/had are referring to yourself in the present/past.  The subject is *you*.  So you'd stick with the same verb tense as the rest of the email.  That said "had discussed [it]" can likely be replaced with simply "discussed [it]" if you're using past tense.

Comment: I would understand your doubt if it were whether to use "I discussed" or "I have discussed".  I had discussed is "past perfect tense" and refers to an action that happened in the past, before a second action. e.g.  " We had discussed the situation when she arrived"  which means the situation had already been discussed when she arrived.

Comment: p.s.  For yesterday night, I presume each verb tense might fit depending on context.  e.g.  I had discussed it with you when Jimmy called."  "We discussed it yesterday and I don't want to discuss it again" and "We have discussed it several times and I think I said all I think about it yesterday night.

Comment: Or, in AmE, "...last night..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of 'Have discussed' and 'had discussed', I'd say that 'have discussed' is more recent. Both the terms refer to past events(though, 'have discussed' is considered as present perfect tense). The difference lies in their past.

'Had discussed' is always used when you are referring to a past event that's past with respect to another past event. Basically, 'had discussed(past participle of any verb)' took place a long time back. 
For ex: Let's consider two events that took place in the past.

1. We completed our homework.
2. He came home.(Remember that both are past events)

Now, let us decide what the 1st event was. Say, it's 'We completed our homework'. The second event is automatically 'He came home'. Combining these two sentences, we would write:

*We **had completed**(happened before another past event i.e his arrival) our homework when he **came**(2nd past event) home.*

'Have' is used when the event just got over. Say, your mom arrives when you just completed all the kitchen work. You'd say to her 'I have completed all the kitchen work.'

'just' is just an explicit explanation of how recent the past event(which 'have' has already suggested) was.

Since your discussion happened last night(you must never say 'yesterday night'), you could use 'I discussed with you last night that...'. Simple past makes it look neither too recent nor too past. That's simple and sweet!

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

While referring to **recent past** events, what's common is the use of "just" with the verb in either *present perfect* or *past indefinite* tense. "had discussed" is *past perfect* tense, which has special rules and unique circumstances governing its usage and therefore it isn't appropriate here.

So, it's neither "I have discussed with you" nor "I had discussed with you". Why?
Neither of them implies that this discussion happened recently.

In order to add that *recent past* time reference to it, it's better to say:
"I (have) just discussed (it) with you", if it happened, say, a couple of hours ago, or "I just discussed (it) with you yesterday".

Answer (score 0):

we always use 3rd form of verb with (has), (have) and (had). and this is called perfect tense.
like in present perfect we will make sentence like (e.g) we have eaten food. in past perfect we will make sentence like we had eaten food and in future perfect tense we will make sentence like we will have eaten food.